# Multi Select List of Values Checkbox - Tableau or Jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports, data-visualization, tableau-api

I want to have an AND functionality instead of OR Functionality for Multi Select List of Values checkbox.

Imagine i am trying to book an hotel. I want all the rooms which have AC and TV

Currently in tableau when i select AC it shows me all the rooms which have AC, then if i select TV then it shows me all the rooms that have TV and AC. BUT it also shows me all the rooms which have JUST AC or JUST have TV. How can i just see rooms that have BOTH AC and TV and filter out the rest ?

I would prefer to do it in Jaspersoft but tableau is fine as well to understand the logic.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using $X{IN,column_name, parameter_name}. Manipulate your parameter in jasper using scriplet or if you are using that filter in sub data set of report then you can easily convert it. Like ['AC','TV'] replace each comma with your column name. Something like would work parameter_name.toStrings().replaceAll("[", "column_name = '").replaceAll("]","'").replaceAll(",","' column_name = '").

Comment: Thanks Fahad for replying. Just to clarify a user will select TV /AC/or any item from the drop down menu in Jasperserver. I am not getting your point where you want me to replace , and [ ... where would i do that ? Also i have a sub data set that i just created for the table.

Comment: Create one parameter with string type in sub data set Let say "parameter_string" is the name. Then map actual parameter say "parameter_List" to that newly created parameter inside the data set. Like parameter_string = parameter_List.toStrings().replaceAll("[", "column_name = '").replaceAll("]","'").replaceAll(",","' column_name = '"). and use this parameter in your data set with $P!{parameter_string}

Comment: Could you please tell your table structure as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553891/filter-rows-with-and-condition

Comment: sorry for late reply fahad the example was just temp, I have created another question with the real tables